# Given a relation $R$, what is the $R^{-1}$, and what is the complement of $R$ on $A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For example if I have the following group $A$ and a relation $R$:
    $$A= {1,2,3}$$
    $$R= \{(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(1,2)(3,2)\}$$
    $$R^{-1} = ?$$ $$R^C = \;?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse Relation (Definition)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373528/inverse-relation-definition)

Comment: See for $R^{-1}$ [Inverse Relation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Inverse_Relation) and [Complement of Relation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Complement_of_Relation).

Comment: The complement of $R \subset A\times A$ is given by $(A\times A)\setminus R$, i.e., $(A\times A) \cap \lnot R$. Also used is the notation: the complement of $R \subset A\times A$ is given by $(A\times A)-R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ R^{-1} = \{(x,y) \mid (y,x) \in R\}$$
$$ R^C = \{ (x,y) \in A \times A \mid (x,y) \notin R\}$$
so with

$$ R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(3,2)\}$$

we get

$$R^{-1} = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(2,1),(2,3)\}$$
$$R^C = \{(2,1),(2,3),(1,3),(3,1)\}$$

Also, there was no significance of calling $A$ a group. Calling it the set
$$ A = \{1,2,3\}$$
is enough for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} A\times A &= \{(x, y)\mid (x\in A) \land (y\in A)\} \\ &= \{(1, 1), (1,2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3. 2), (3, 3)\}\end{align}$$

$$R\subset A\times A = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(3,2)\}\tag{given}$$

$$R^{-1} = \{(y, x) \mid (x, y) \in R \} = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3)\}\tag{inverse of $R$}$$

$$\begin{align} R^C \subset A\times A &= \{(x, y) \in A\times A \mid (x, y)\notin R\}\\ &= \{(1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1)\}\tag{complement of $R$}\end{align}$$

---

Note that $R^{-1}$ represents the inverse relation of $R$ on $A$.

Also, $R^C \subset A\times A$ represents the complement of the relation $R$ on $A$, and that $R \cup R^{C} = A\times A$.