# Residuation in $Rel(X)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relation-algebra

Following the definition from [residuated lattice](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/residuated+lattice), then we have that for any $R$, $S$ and $T$ in $Rel(X)$ (all the binary relations on a set $X$):
$$
   R ; S \subseteq T \iff S \subseteq R\backslash T \iff R \subseteq T/S\,.
$$
where $;$ is the composition of relations and where, if $A,B \in Rel(X)$, then
$$
A \backslash B = (A;B^-)^-
$$
and
$$
B/A = (B^-;A^-)^-
$$
where with $A^-$ we mean the complement of the relation ([see also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080996/given-a-relation-r-what-is-the-r-1-and-what-is-the-complement-of-r-on)).

Now I wanted to get a feeling of what these subsets of $X\times X$ are by considering an example, but I there is something wrong in what I am doing.

Take $X = \{1,2,3\}$, and let:

- $R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(2,1),(3,2)\}$ and
- $S = \{(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$.

Then we have that $R;S = \{(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$.

Take $T = (R;S) \cup \{(1,1)\}$, so that $R;S \subseteq T$.

Then we have $T^- = \{(2,1)\}$ and thus $R;T^- = \{(2,1),(3,1)\}$.

But now we have that:
$$
S\not\subseteq R\backslash T=(R;T^-)^- = \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3)\}
$$
as $\{(3,1)\} \in S$ but $\{(3,1)\}\notin R\backslash T$.

If we choose to add $\{(2,1)\}$ to $R;S$ to form $T$ then I see things work out fine.